# Deploy react app in docker with subroute using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, react-router-dom

I have a server that has nginx installed to configure a reverse proxy to work with a subroute (example: https://my_server/my_app), this server has a container where a react application is deployed that uses the "react-router-dom" library

Configuration external Nginx:

```
  location /my-app/ {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:port_docker_container/my-app/;
  }
```

Configuration internal (Docker container) Nginx:

```
  location / {
    root              /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html
  }
```

My index.html is in /usr/share/nginx/html/my-app/index.html

My package.json is:

```
  "homepage": "/my-app",
```

My browserrouter is (index.js):

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login">
                    <LoginPage />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/explorer">
                    <InnerApp />
                </Route>
                <Route path="/">
                    <HomePage />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Box>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The index and the statics are loaded correctly but the navigation does not work well and when I enter it removes the text "my-app" from the url

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what is missing is telling the router what/where it is handling routing/navigation actions relative to. This is handled by providing a [`basename`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) prop to the router component.

> The base URL for all locations. If your app is served from a
> sub-directory on your server, you’ll want to set this to the
> sub-directory.

If the app is served from a `"/my-app"` directory then specify this as the router's base name.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/my-app">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/explorer" component={InnerApp} />
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Box>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```